# Is there a imac mail app available?

Tags: imac, mac-appstore

Is there a mail app for imac ? Closest thing I can find is thunderbird. Something similar to the iphone mail app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [**Mail.app**](http://www.apple.com/macosx/apps/#mail).

It's built in Mac OS X since at least Tiger, works with POP, IMAP and Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, anything for yahoo mail, gmail etc ?

Comment: I just read the doc, it seems to support yahoo mail & gmail

Comment: If you want something that looks and feels a little more like the iPhone app, try Sparrow - there is a free version on the Mac App Store, this was originally specifically written for Gmail, but has recently been updated to work with most mail systems.